# Paperclip problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the video upload applicaton. I am using thoughbot paperclip plugin for uploading video files and i convert the video files into "flv" format by using ffmpeg .

The problem is the users can also upload the "flv" video files, in this case the browser keeping of waiting, the bottom of the browser its  shows "sending request to localhost:3000".

When i see the mongral log nothing happed, the server sits idle.

When i upload the other video file format its working fine .. i am not sure what is happening.

here is my model file coding :

```
has_attached_file :source,:styles => {:thumb => "137x85>" }

validates_attachment_content_type 
   :source, 
   :content_type => ['video/x-   
       msvideo','video/avi','video/quicktime','video/3gpp','video/x-ms-
       wmv','video/mp4', 'flv-application/octet-stream','video/x-
       flv','video/mpeg','video/mpeg4','video/x-la-asf','video/x-ms-asf'],

   :message => "Only Video file at the moment"
```

Comment: Please show your view too. Your problem is probably there.

Comment: Even you're using `validates_attachment_content_type`, the file will be get uploaded first before its type get validated. Probably you should check that mongrel can handle FLV upload.